# what is underlying data structure of STL list, vector and set?

Tags: c++, list, stl, vector, set

what is underlying data structure of STL list, vector and set ?

My solution:

- vector : (dynamic allocated) array
- list: ?
- set: heap (or a binary tree with all leaf nodes located as left as possible and keep min/max element on top)

Right?

Comment: Implementation defined, but generally, `std::vector` is a dynamically allocated array. `std::list` is a doubly linked list (C++11 introduces `std::forward_list` which is a singly linked list), and a `set` is generally based on [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), though anything that fits the amortized complexity and behavior requirements of the interfaces defined in the standard are acceptable implementations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on comments, to clarify, these are the most common choices, but based on desired complexity and other factors, the backing of these implementations may vary:

[Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) = dynamically resizing array

List = [Doubly Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)

Set = [Red/Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) (balanced Binary Search Tree)

I think you might possibly be mixing up Heaps and BSTs.  A heap is visualized as a tree, but it's actually built on top of an indexable list structure (e.g. array or vector).  C++ provides heap functions via the [algorithm header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) in the STL .  BSTs are more of a key/value based structure used for efficient lookup (which is what you generally want for a set).

Comment: This is usually true, but note that this is not the only option (it's implementation-dependent).

Comment: @sgusc , map is red-black tree, set is not because elements on it are not sorted. What is diff between list and linked list ? what is data structure of "linked list" ? a list?

Comment: This is Implementation Dependent but the complexity which the Standard demands leaves little options for drastically varying implementations.

Comment: @user1002288 - `std::set` has ordering requirements. C++11's `std::unordered_set` doesn't. A [doubly-linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is a group of nodes that have references to the node before it and after it (or `NULL`).

Comment: Although in practice you are right, the standard library implementation is free to use whatever data structures it likes, as long as they fulfill the guarantees and interfaces specified in the standard.

Comment: @Praetorian Good call.  I'll clarify.

Comment: @avakar, true, but `std::list` supports bidirectional iterators and `--` must be constant time. Plus the other time constraints it'd be a challenge to implement list not using a double-linked list.

Comment: Granted it can vary.  Map, Set, MultiSet and MultiMap are really Abstract Data Types (ADTs) that define behavior.  The underlying implementation could be implemented with any data structure (generally a BST variant or a hashtable) depending on desired complexity and the implementer's whims.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, I was actually not responding to @Praetorian and was referring to `set`, which can easily be implemented in numerous ways :)

Answer (score 5):

The standard gives no guarantees on what data structures are used, there are only complexity guarantees, so the implementation can choose any structure that fulfills them.

That said, `std::vector` is usually a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), `std::list` is probably a [doubly-linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) and `std::set` is most often some kind of [self-balancing binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).